# Aspnet_wp is showing up with a strange name in Task Manager

Tags: asp.net, process, task-manager

Instead of "aspnet_wp," AS61FF~1.EXE is displayed, having User Name ASPNET. I took a look in Process Explorer, and indeed, that strangely named process is aspnet_wp. Why would it be displayed this way in Task Manager?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think that is an NTFS shortname for aspnet_wp.exe, but I don't know why some processes are shown in Task Manager by their shortnames (and I never saw system processes with shortnames there).